# how come resolvconf update /etc/resolve.conf file even if systemd-resovled service is disabled?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

I disabled systemd-resoved service and set nameserver in raspberry pi to my local dns, but I discovered it on reboot it got changed. To nameserver I don't know where it came from and how it is generated by resolvconf.

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.248.114.129
nameserver 1.8.14.193
```

Comment: On a normal installation, `/etc/resolve.conf` is a symlink. If you disable systemd-resolved, then also delete the symlink and create a normal `/etc/resolve.conf` to your liking. If for some reason any program still wants to change your `/etc/resolve.conf` you can make it immutable with this command: `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: my raspberry pi os is from raspberrypi.org , I assume its normal installation ..